# Update my main activity after volley call in the detail Activity

Tags: android, android-volley

I have two activity :
1- main activity which has a list of items (Main activity) 
2- activity to add item (Add activity)

in the Add activity I am using volley library to add item to the server and I will receive this item from server with its id and then I want to pass this item to the Main activity, I was sending static ListAdapter which point to Main activity List Adapter to Add activity to solve this problem, but now I have more than one call to Add activity so this solutions become not good for me.

What is the best solution to send the item from Add activity to Main activity after finishing of Volley request.

Note : Add activity maybe finished before finishing of Volley request. 
so I cannot use start Activity for result.

Comment: "Add activity maybe finished before finishing of Volley request" why should it be finished before ? Make it finish after request completed

Comment: I don't want to make user waiting for that

Comment: Then put a lock on ListAdapter while request has not been completed and remove the lock after completion

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking into otto. You can post an event on the main thread when Volley finishes its request. If add is still up it can setResult and Main can handle onActivityResult. If main is up, it will get the event directly and do what it needs to. http://square.github.io/otto/